# If $\frac{2x + 6} {(x + 2)^2}- \frac{2} {x + 2} = \frac{a} {(x + 2)^2}$, then what is $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{2x + 6} {(x + 2)^2}- \frac{2} {x + 2}$$

The expression above is equivalent to $$\frac{a} {(x + 2)^2}$$
where $a$ is a positive constant and $x \neq -2$.
What's the value of $a$?

Comment: $$\begin{align}\frac{2x + 6} {(x + 2)^2}- \frac{2} {x + 2} &= \frac{a} {(x + 2)^2} \\ \therefore \frac{2x + 6} {(x + 2)^2}- \frac{2\color{red}{(x+2)}} {(x + 2)\color{red}{(x+2)}} &= \frac{a} {(x + 2)^2} \\ \therefore \frac{2x + 6-2(x+2)}{\require{cancel}{\cancel{(x + 2)^2}}} &= \frac{a} {\cancel{(x + 2)^2}} \\ \therefore 2x + 6-2(x+2) &= a.\end{align}$$  Can you simplify from here? :) (Side note: of course since this equality is true for any $x\neq -2$, you can arbitrarily substitute in any value of $x$ except $-2$ and then numerically solve for $a$. In @lhf's answer, $x=0$ was substituted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do any algebra.

Consider
$$
\frac{2x + 6} {(x + 2)^2}- \frac{2} {x + 2}
=
\frac{a} {(x + 2)^2}
$$
Since this equality holds for all values of $x\ne -2$,
set $x=0$ and get
$$
\frac{6} {2^2}- \frac{2} {2}
=
\frac{a} {2^2}
$$
which gives $a=2$.

Comment: Why set x to 0?

Comment: The equality has to hold for all values of $x \ne -2$. You can use other values of $x$ if you want; $0$ is just the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Through basic substitution one finds:

$$a =\frac{2 \left(x^4+5 x^3+7 x^2+3 x-4\right)}{x}$$

not a positive constant.

Comment: But now this adds another constraint, that $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$2x+\frac{6}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{2}{x+2}=\frac{a}{(x+2)^2}$$
$$2x(x+2)^2+6-2(x+2)=a$$
$$2x^3+4x^2+4x+6-2x-2=a$$
$$2x^3+4x^2+2x+4=a$$

Comment: i think he meant $2x + \frac{6}{(x+2)^2}$

Comment: The person who posed the question must fix the math typography before we waste time solving the wrong problem.

Comment: I think you meant poster. And yes

Comment: Well, in the new edit, the expression $2x+\dfrac{6}{(x+2)^2}$ should instead be $\dfrac{2x+6}{(x+2)^2}$ :/